# Session variable not passing to another page

Tags: php

Why my session variable is not passing between these 2 pages?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["test"]= "12345";
echo "<a href='8.php'>move to another page</a>";
?>
```

second webpage 2.php

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

The session variable is empy in the second page

Comment: You should also use `session_start()` in second page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set `session_start()` on every page on which you want to see `$_SESSION` array. It is nice to have one file in which you will set `session_start()` and include it on every page on which you want to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

> Why my session variable is not passing between these 2 pages?

Add the `session_start()` to your webpage2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["test"];
?>
```

Read more info about session [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)